# Product by two groups SAS

Tags: sas, product, accumulate

I am trying to create a product by two groups: `id1` and `id2`.

Here's how the dataset looks like:

```
data test;
    input id1 id2 value;
    datalines;

1 199001 1.762681948
1 199001 1.775245162
1 199001 1.428673376
1 199002 1.175974146
1 199002 1.236166022
1 199002 1.608842974
1 199003 1.673956674
1 199003 1.05879051
1 199003 1.565500916
2 199002 1.838999925
2 199002 .
2 199002 1.984415322
2 199003 1.096820927
2 199003 1.734215557
2 199003 1.157566337
;
run;
```

I want to create a product of the last columns `value`, based on the first and second columns.
I.e. the output for group `id1=1` and `id2=199001` should be: `1.7626x1.7775x1.429=4.47`. I.e the output should look like:

```
1   199001  4.47059416
1   199002  2.338773875
1   199003  2.774645982
2   199002  .
2   199003  2.201834613
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the missing value?  Do you want to ignore it like what would happen with a SUM aggregation?  Or cause it to force a missing result like would happen if you just did simple addition (or multiplication) with a missing value?

Comment: Force a missing result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect example for the best trifecta in SAS: `first./last.`, `retain`, and by-group processing.

```
data want;
    set test;
    by id1 id2;
    retain product;

    if(first.id2) then product = value;
        else product = product * value;

    if(last.id2) then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use fact that multiplication converts to addition if you work with the LOG() of the values.  Then you could use the SUM() aggregate function of SQL.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as
  select id1,id2,exp(sum(log(value))) as product
  from have
  group by 1,2
;
quit;
```

If we require the presence of a missing value to return a missing value then add a CASE statement.  You might also want to add logic to deal with zeros.

```
create table want as
  select id1,id2
       , case
           when (sum(value=0)) then 0
           when (sum(missing(value))) then .
           else exp(sum(log(case when (value) then value else 1 end)))
         end as product
  from have
  group by 1,2
;
```

The inner CASE will eliminate notes about trying to take the LOG() of zero or missing values.

The code uses the fact that SAS boolean logic generates 1 for true and zero for false and evaluates values of zero or missing as false with any other value being considered as true.